# Music/voice sometimes plays only in one earphone, fixed after reboot

Tags: volume

Sometimes, my phone plays sound (both music and voice calls) only through one earphone. In such cases:

- Unplugging/re-plugging the earphones doesn't fix it, including a different earphone set.
- Restarting the phone does fix it.

Is this a known issue? What is the cause of it? How can I avoid this state?

OS: Windows Phone 8.1 version 8.10.12359.845, but happened in previous versions as well.
Phone: Lumia 920, with included earphones.

Comment: I've have the same setup. Never happen to me. You sure the cable is in very good state? Sometimes I lost contact temporarily because this.

Comment: +1 I have got exactly same behavior. Also with both systems now with 8.1, bot even before that with 8.0. (phone Nokia Lumia 925, any headphones).
But for now, your question is not really a question. Either add some question to it (maybe: what is causing this?) or reformulate current question to an qustion&answer (Q: playing one headphone-how to fix it? A: reboot.).

Comment: Added questions, though I believe they'd be fairly obvious...

Comment: Exactly same behaviour on OS : 8.10.14234.375 too. The problem persists.